# Vacuous proof of $a+b+c=0$

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

*"Prove that if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are odd integers such that $a+b+c=0$, then $abc < 0$"*

My attempt: I figured that since you can't make an odd by adding two other odd numbers there was no way to get to $0$ the way it shows so I wrote:

$a+b \ne$ odd, therefore $a+b+c \ne 0$, so the implication is true (since the condition is always false)

I'm not entirely sure how to do this, the textbook didn't give that many examples for trivial and vacuous proofs. What is the strategy for questions regarding odd/even proofs?

Comment: The first statement is impossible. There are no three odd numbers such that $a+b+c=0$. Hence anything you derive from this is also not true. E.g. Let $a=2d+1$, $b=2e+1$, $c=2f+1$ hence $2d+2e+2f+3=0$. Then modulo 2 gives that $1=0$ and you can use this to prove anything false you like. E.g. $abc=1\times abc=0\times abc=0$ which disproves what you wanted to prove.

Comment: @IanMiller: It is certainly possible to derive something true from something untrue. A contradiction allows you to conclude _anything_ irrespective of whether it's true or not.

Comment: Your argument is I think sufficient, probably no further detail is expected.

Comment: There are no odd integers following your constraint. It is easy to see: Odds are not closed under addition. Because $a+b=-c$ where the left hand-side is even and the right hand side is odd, you reach a contridiction.

Comment: @IanMiller You wrote "anything you derive from [a false statement] is also not true" -- this is manifestly incorrect.  Indeed, *any* conclusion (including true ones!) can be deduced from a false premise, which is precisely the OP's point.

Comment: I meant anything you derive from the false statement has no value. Sorry for poor phrasing.

Comment: @IanMiller: From $0=1$ I can derive $2+2=4$. Do you contend that $2+2=4$ somehow "has no value"?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why someone would downvote or vote to close. This is a perfectly reasonable question that shows effort.

Comment: The argument looks fine to me. OK, if you were writing a textbook I'd expect a little more detail and formality in the part showing $a+b+c\neq 0$, but you obviously grasped why this is so; and you clearly understand that this immediately proves the implication true, which I suspect is the main point of the exercise.

Comment: As @mweiss states any conclusion can be derived from a false premise so any conclusion is as valuable as any other conclusion. Using it to prove $2+2=4$ and using it to prove $1=0$ are equal in usefulness so neither can be given any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to phrase an argument like this is to use modular arithmetic - as used in the comments, if something is even, we write $a\equiv 0 \mod 2$. Because these statements are so 'obvious' e.g. the sum of three odd numbers is odd, you typically wouldn't bother proving it, you'd just take it as given.

However, if you're working at a very basic level learning some formal logic, it's worth seeing a clear proof. The general method is to *define* an even integer $a$ as an integer that can can be written as $a=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Similarly, an odd number is any $b$ that can be written as $b=2l+1$ for some $l\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So then you can show if $a, b, c$ are odd, then there are three integers $k, m, n$ such that $a=2k+1$, etc. Then $a+b+c=2k+1+2m+1+2n+1=2(k+m+n)+3=2(k+m+n+1)+1$, so this is odd, while $0$ is even.

Then your conclusion works perfectly; the condition is always false, so the implication is true.

Comment: Ahhh I started out like that but for some reason thought that was the wrong way to go about it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Technically, I'd like to see a statement showing that "even" and "odd" are disjoint categories. (Bonus points for the fact that they cover the integers.)

Comment: As I wrote this answer I thought about including caveats about disjointness, but I figured it wouldn't be appropriate for a simple formal logic course. Now that I think about it, how would you prove that? Division algorithm? I suppose eventually you have to push back to something like Peano axioms anyway, or take *some* level of intuition for granted.